# How can nginx match the following rules?

Tags: nginx

#### now config

```
location = /admin {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090
}
```

#### result

404 not found

#### i want result

example.com/admin -> http://127.0.0.1:8090

example.com/admin/test -> http://127.0.0.1:8090/test

example.com/admin/one -> http://127.0.0.1:8090/one

Answer (score 0):

Remove the equal sign:

```
location /admin {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090
}
```

Then it should work as you expect.

Comment: i remove the equal sign, the rule match  http://127.0.0.1:8090/admin, i want match  http://127.0.0.1:8090

Comment: Then do `location /`?